# How to add VM arguments in Launch4j

Tags: java, javafx, jvm-arguments, launch4j

I've had some confusion in trying to create a `.exe` file to run my JavaFX application.

In Eclipse I use the VM Argument:

```
--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-14.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

But I'm not sure how to add it to `Launch4j` to be able to run it. Could someone show me how to add it?

Comment: You don't know the struggle I went through to make this work. This was the last piece; believe it or not.

Answer (score 5):

In launch4j, Look under the "JRE" tab. There is a textarea to add JVM options.
[There is a ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc813.png)

Comment: Stupid me, I put them under "Command line arguments". That caused the it to actually work when testing from Launch4j, but not when the .exe was executed from Windows. This fixed the issue.