# How do I run a executable jar with VM arguments?

Tags: java, javafx, jar, exe

I have a JavaFX application, that uses SceneBuilder, and has 2 VM arguments, and when I export it in Eclipse as a runnable jar file, it says that:

"VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR. Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR"

I still exported it though, but it wouldn't run.
And I cant figure out how to add the arguments to the jar, and I also wanna convert it to a .exe with Launch4j

Anyone know how to add the VM Arguments to the jar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying JVM arguments when calling a jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891123/specifying-jvm-arguments-when-calling-a-jar-file)

Comment: And for Launch4J: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62508328/438992

Comment: Executable JAR + JavaFX = Just don't do this!

Comment: If you want to create an `exe` (not an executable `jar`), then [here is one way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811401/how-to-create-a-standalone-exe-in-java-that-runs-without-an-installer-and-a-jr) (includes some discussion of alternate packaging approaches).